# Manual Login with Paypal

Tags: javascript, paypal

I tried to integrate login with paypal without paypal's api.js, however I could not find a documentation for it.

Here is what I tried

**HTML**

```
<img id="paypalVerify" src="~/Images/getverifiedbypaypal.jpg" onclick="windowPop()" />
```

**JS**

```
<script>
            function windowPop() {

                //Create Form Attributes
                var paypalForm = document.createElement("paypalForm");
                paypalForm.target = "paypalPopup1";
                paypalForm.method = "POST"; // or "post" if appropriate
                paypalForm.action = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/auth/loginauth";

                //Paypal Application ID
                var appid = document.createElement("input");
                appid.type = "text";
                appid.name = "appid";
                appid.value = "**************";
                paypalForm.appendChild(appid);

                //Paypal authend
                var authend = document.createElement("input");
                authend.type = "text";
                authend.name = "authend";
                authend.value = "sandbox";
                paypalForm.appendChild(authend);

                //Paypal scopes
                var scopes = document.createElement("input");
                scopes.type = "text";
                scopes.name = "scopes";
                scopes.value = "profile email address phone";
                paypalForm.appendChild(scopes);

                //Paypal locale
                var locale = document.createElement("input");
                locale.type = "text";
                locale.name = "locale";
                locale.value = "en-us";
                paypalForm.appendChild(locale);

                //Paypal locale
                var returnurl = document.createElement("input");
                returnurl.type = "text";
                returnurl.name = "returnurl";
                returnurl.value = "http://localhost:57559/";
                paypalForm.appendChild(returnurl);

                document.body.appendChild(paypalForm);

                var paypalPopup = window.open("", "paypalPopup1", "status=0,title=0,height=600,width=800,scrollbars=1");
                if (paypalPopup) {
                    paypalForm.submit();
                } else {
                    alert('You must allow popups for this map to work.');
                }
            }
        </script>
```

I tried to create a form then also created the pop up box with form data, when the login with paypal clicked and after pop up created tried to submit the form.

I am pretty sure that the problem is both with JS and Paypal's missing documentation or my fault. My main purpose to do this is, I just want to customize loginwithpaypal button, I want to change its text.

I will appreciate any helps

If I use api.js, I could succesfully integrate but as I said I could not find docs to customize api.js's button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  paypal.use(["login"], function (login) {
            login.render({
                "appid": "-************",
                "authend": "sandbox",
                "scopes": "profile email address phone",
                "containerid": "paypalLogin",
                "locale": "en-us",
                "text": "Verify your account with Paypal",
                "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:57559/"
       });
   });
});
```

while creating the button request as a text attribute, we can set the button text

[Here is THE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3acotj9r/1)

Comment: I can get the login to work fine, but after it verifies, it just redirects the popup to the ```returnurl``` instead of the page that opened the popup. Ideas on how to close the window and redirect the page that triggered the pop up?

Comment: return url must match with host, port and protocol, so you need to assign your return url with your current domain than that's it

Comment: @evliu and also return url is the wrong parameter, it was my fault, it must be redirect_uri